# Trigger number counter on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this simple query for a number counter and I was hoping someone could show me how to trigger it on scroll? Id like it to trigger when the div is within say 500px for the top of the browser.

Also, is there any way I can have a comma in the number? For example "18,000". If I add the comma in it seems to break the script (still leaning jQuery).

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="18000">0</div>
```

Comment: So basically you want to increment the counter on scroll

Comment: actually the scroll wont work on SO snippet..a jsfiddle would be better option

Comment: adding comma is converting the number to string...hence the break

Comment: Yep. I just want infographics to trigger (and the numbers count up) and the user scrolls down the page